# Sutherland Hodgman polygon clipping Algorithm

Tags: c, bgi

Sutherland hodgeman polygon clipping algorithm is where we are interested in clipping or getting only some particular part of the given polygon. I know the concept of clipping and I saw the following code on the web :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <process.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
typedef unsigned int outcode;
outcode CompOutCode(float x,float y);
enum  {  TOP = 0x1,
BOTTOM = 0x2,
RIGHT = 0x4,
LEFT = 0x8
};
float xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax;
void clip(float x0,float y0,float x1,float y1)
{
outcode outcode0,outcode1,outcodeOut;
int accept = FALSE,done = FALSE;
outcode0 = CompOutCode(x0,y0);
outcode1 = CompOutCode(x1,y1);
do
{
    if(!(outcode0|outcode1))
    {
        accept = TRUE;
        done = TRUE;
    }
    else
    if(outcode0 & outcode1)
        done = TRUE;
    else
    {
        float x,y;
        outcodeOut = outcode0?outcode0:outcode1;
        if(outcodeOut & TOP)
        {
            x = x0+(x1-x0)*(ymax-y0)/(y1-y0);
            y = ymax;
        }
        else if(outcodeOut & BOTTOM)
        {
            x = x0+(x1-x0)*(ymin-y0)/(y1-y0);
            y = ymin;
        }
        else if(outcodeOut & RIGHT)
        {
            y = y0+(y1-y0)*(xmax-x0)/(x1-x0);
            x = xmax;
        }
        else
        {
            y = y0+(y1-y0)*(xmin-x0)/(x1-x0);
            x = xmin;
        }
        if(outcodeOut==outcode0)
        {
            x0 = x;
            y0 = y;
            outcode0 = CompOutCode(x0,y0);
        }
        else
        {
            x1 = x;
            y1 = y;
            outcode1 = CompOutCode(x1,y1);
          }
    }
}while(done==FALSE);
if(accept)
    line(x0,y0,x1,y1);
outtextxy(150,20,"POLYGON AFTER CLIPPING");
rectangle(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax);
}
outcode CompOutCode(float x,float y)
{
    outcode code = 0;
    if(y>ymax)
        code|=TOP;
    else if(y<ymin)
            code|=BOTTOM;
    if(x>xmax)
        code|=RIGHT;
    else if(x<xmin)
        code|=LEFT;
    return code;
}
void main( )
{
float x1,y1,x2,y2;
/* request auto detection */
int gdriver = DETECT, gmode, n,poly[14],i;
clrscr( );
printf("Enter the no of sides of polygon:");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("\nEnter the coordinates of polygon\n");
for(i=0;i<2*n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&poly[i]);
}
poly[2*n]=poly[0];
poly[2*n+1]=poly[1];
printf("Enter the rectangular coordinates of clipping window\n");
scanf("%f%f%f%f",&xmin,&ymin,&xmax,&ymax);
/* initialize graphics and local variables */
initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "c:\\tc\\bgi");

outtextxy(150,20,"POLYGON BEFORE CLIPPING");
drawpoly(n+1,poly);
rectangle(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax);
getch( );
cleardevice( );
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
clip(poly[2*i],poly[(2*i)+1],poly[(2*i)+2],poly[(2*i)+3]);
getch( );
restorecrtmode( );
}
```

The coding was well written and I have the real problem of understanding the `clip` function defined in the code. Since I'm a novice in C, I couldn't able to figure it out, can anyone explain the algorithm involved in the `clip` function?

Comment: `Explain this to me step by step` is not a good fit for this site. Try to figure out some specific questions that allow us to post targeted answers. Where should someone start answering you? Explaining what a `float` is? Explaining what `#include` does? ...

Comment: explain what `clip` does. Just an algorithm for `clip`.

Comment: in fact it is an good comment, I edited my question.

Comment: Check the algorithm here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Euuw72Ymu0M

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The algorithm you present is not the Sutherland-Hodgman-Algorithm for clipping against an arbitrary polygon, but the Cohen-Sutherland-Algorithm for clipping against a rectangular viewport. The code snippet seems to be taken directly from the corresponding [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm). That article explains the algorithm and it also explains the code sample step by step, as their version contains many helpful comments. The major idea is to classify the location of the line endpoints with respect to the viewport using a 4-bit code, which makes the actual clipping implementable based on simple bitwise operations.

Assuming you understand the basic programming constructs (like loops, if, ...), basic arithmetics and the basic workings of the algorithm (maybe with the help of Wikipedia), then the key to understanding the code sample is to keep in mind that the C operators `|` and `&` realize bitwise operations.

If you are really looking for the Sutherland-Hodgman-Algorithm to clip against an arbitrary polygon, then completely forget about this code sample. The source you got it from either wrongly attributes this to the Sutherland-Hodgman-Algorithm or you misinterpreted it due to the fact that both algorithms are attributed to Ivan Sutherland, but these are fundamentally different algorithms.